# Descent for the cotangent complex along faithfully flat SCRs

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

By Theorem 3.1 of Bhatt-Morrow-Scholze II (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03261.pdf), we know that for $R$ a commutative ring, $\wedge^{i}L_{(-)/R}$ satisfies descent for faithfully flat maps $A \rightarrow B$ of (ordinary) $R$-algebras. Can this descent statement be promoted to, say, faithfully flat maps of simplicial commutative $R$-algebras (where $R$ is either discrete or a simplicial commutative ring)? I am primarily interested in the case where $i=1$, as the proof of this claim along with an induction argument using a filtration, can probably give the $i>1$ case.

Comment: For what it's worth, the answer to this question is yes, at least for $i=1$. The argument involves proving a flat descent theorem for simplicial commutative rings, and then modifying the argument found in BMS II by using the Bousfield-Kan spectral sequence and the Tor spectral sequence for derived tensor product.

Comment: It seems to me that in a [Bhatt's old paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6193), Proposition 2.7, he proved that the totalization of the cosimplicial object $\wedge^kL_{C(f)^\bullet/A}$ is equivalent to $0$ whenever $f\colon A\to B$ is a map of simplicial commutative rings (without any further hypotheses, which seems stronger than what have been shown in BMS2), where $C(f)^\bullet$ is the Čech conerve. Is the question just a corollary of that?

Comment: The fact you cite is used in an induction argument on the degree of the wedge power. To elaborate, for a sequence of scrs, $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C$, there is a filtration on $\wedge^{k}L_{C/A}$ whose graded pieces are given in terms of lower degree wedge powers of $L_{B/A}$ and $L_{C/B}$. In particular, the sequence $R \rightarrow A \rightarrow B^{\bullet}$ where $B^{\bullet}$ is the Cech conerve of the faithfully flat map $A \rightarrow B$, gives the desired filtration to induct on.

Comment: This reduces the claim to proving claims (1) and (2) appearing in Theorem 3.1 of arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03261.pdf for the wedge powers. In summary, the same argument that appears in BMS2 works for simplicial commutative rings as well.

Comment: I don't know whether my understanding is correct. The proposition I quoted is a stronger version (without faithfulness and flatness) of the assertion (2) in the proof of Thm 3.1 of BMS2. Therefore the simplicial version of Thm 3.1 should be considered a direct consequence of that? (The large portion of the proof in BMS2 is devoted to assertion (2))